# JXplorer doesn't show LDAP schema

Tags: schema, openldap

I've got a problem with JXplorer and other LDAP browsers - they don't show schema under schema tab.
I use OpenLdap 2.4. I'm using OLC i.e. I'm running slapd daemon with the -F option.
I can connect to cn=schema,cn=config and view/modify schema there.

But I want to be able to see the schema in the LDAP browsers like JXplorer.

What may I do wrong? Maybe I'm missing any important point here?
Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Works for me. Must be something odd about your OpenLDAP setup.

Comment: Yea, but what could it be? I've got a really simple config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a permissions case:

```
access to dn.base="" by * read
access to dn.base="cn=Subschema" by * read
```